# Why do my high and low pass filters look like high pass filters in LTSpice plot?

Tags: ltspice, low-pass, high-pass-filter

I am new to this and trying to learn about designing analogue audio filters. I looked at a couple of tutorials online that gave examples about how to implement and simulate high and low pass filters. I used the internal plot tool to checkout the output using a decade sweep, but both my high and low pass filters exhibit high pass filter behaviour. The filters themselves are first order filters, where the only difference is I have swapped the position of the capacitor and resistor. I could provide the settings I put into the AC Analysis simulation command, but I believe the **.ac dec 20 1 20k** section describes that adequately. I hope I have shared enough info to make my mistake obvious to anybody that can help.

[image: low pass filter]

[image: high pass filter]

Comment: Did you remember to click the simulate button after you rearranged the components?

Comment: Hi @Carl. Yes, I even saved them as separate files and closed them and reopened them. If I change the resistance values it moves the frequency of the filter cutoffs, so I feel like I'm updating things accordingly in the application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look what you have plotted in both graphs: -

[image]

And, of course both circuits will have the same input current no matter which position the R and C are in. You need to plot Vout.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was unsure about how to add a Vout type component onto the circuit, what is that control called in the application, please?

Comment: Vout is just what I call the node that connects the resistor and capacitor so, plot the voltage on that node i.e, something like V(n002) but better still, add a node label to that node called Vout and, plot V(Vout) @RobHinchliff

Comment: Thank you for explaining this, LTSpice makes much more sense now.